# Why can't I have two methods with ArrayList parameters?

Tags: java, exception, generics, methods, arraylist

Why can't I make two overloaded methods whose parameters are both array lists, but with different data types?

```
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ints.add(1);
    ints.add(2);
    ints.add(3);
    ints.add(4);
    ints.add(5);

    showFirst(ints);

    ArrayList<Double> dubs = new ArrayList<Double>();
    dubs.add(1.1);
    dubs.add(2.2);
    dubs.add(3.3);
    dubs.add(4.4);
    dubs.add(5.5);

    showFirst(dubs);
  } 

  public static void showFirst(ArrayList<Integer> a)
  {
    System.out.println(a.remove(0));
  }

  public static void showFirst(ArrayList<Double> a)
  {
    System.out.println(a.remove(0));
  }
}
```

I am in eclipse, and it underlines the problem causing code in red and gives this message: `Method showFirst(ArrayList<Integer>) has the same erasure showFirst(ArrayList<E>) as another method in type test`

The only way I could get it to work is my adding other parameters, such as `, int b` after `showFirst(ArrayList<Integer> a` and `, int b` after `showFirst(ArrayList<Double> a`.

Is there any way to make this code work the way I intended? If not, I'd like to know why this is happening.

Running the program generates the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
  The method showFirst(ArrayList<Integer>) in the type test is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Double>)
at test.test.main(test.java:25)
```

Edit:

Using  or , what if I wanted to do things where I need the data type such as:

```
public static int[] reverseInArray(ArrayList<Integer> a)
  {
    int n = a.size();
    int[] b = new int[n];
    while(n > 0)
    {
    b[n] = a.remove(0);
    n--;
    }
    return b;
  }

  public static double[] reverseInArray(ArrayList<Double> a)
  {
    double n = a.size();
    double[] b = new int[n];
    while(I > 0)
    {
    b[n] = a.remove(0);
    n--;
    }
    return b;
  }
```

Comment: Look into type erasure.

Answer (score 12):

At run time, every `ArrayList<Whatever>` will be converted to `ArrayList` (raw) due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). So, just have one method that receives `List<? extends Number>`.

```
//renamed to show what the method really does
public static void removeFirst(List<? extends Number> a) {
    System.out.println(a.remove(0));
}
```

Note that the method above will work only for `List`s (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList` and other implementations of `List`) which declares to hold a class that extends from `Number`. If you want/need a method to remove the first element from `List` that holds any type, use `List<?>` instead:

```
public static void removeFirst(List<?> a) {
    System.out.println(a.remove(0));
}
```

Remember to always [program to interfaces instead of specific class implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197).

Comment: +1 In fact, `List<?>` would be the most appropriate.

Comment: @PaulBellora answer updated reflecting the difference between `List<? extends Number>` and `List<?>`.

Comment: +1 as an advice.. method's name should be the most declarative as possible  ..if you call a method `showFirst` i expect that that method don't remove an element from the list!

Answer (score 3):

Generics are only enforced at compile time. At runtime an `ArrayList` is an `ArrayList`.

You can combine the two methods in this particular case, though:

```
public static void showFirst(ArrayList<? extends Number> a)
{
    System.out.println(a.remove(0));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because generics are *erased* at runtime. In other words, your code doesn't know that the two methods are different. In fact, you have another compiler error that you're not telling us about:

```
Method showFirst(ArrayList<Integer>) has the same erasure showFirst(ArrayList<E>) as another method in type Main
```

Answer (score 3):

... because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), your generic parameters are unknown at runtime, hence your overridden methods share an ambiguous signature.

Answer (score 2):

Have this method only, because, generics are available only in compile, so, both of your methods are compiled to same signature. So it's ambiguous which method to be called

```
public static void showFirst(ArrayList<? extends Number> a)
{
    System.out.println(a.remove(0));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: -1 `generics are available only in runtime,` not true at all.. at compile-time ;)

Comment: @Nachokk : Corrected, It was a typo.